# Отправка данных из приложения в формате pdf

Tags: pdf, ios

Есть приложение с тестом. Как возможно реализовать отправку тестовых данных (ответов и результатов теста) на email компании в формате pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Создать PDF из UITextView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html)
2. [Отправить на почту](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10309610/887325)

Answer (score 0):

Если разрабатываете под Xamarin.IOs, можно попробовать создать PDF на девайсе при помощи [Apitron PDF Kit](http://blog.apitron.com/2015/01/manipulate-pdf-on-ios-and-android-using-apitron-pdf-kit-and-xamarin.html) и в клауд сторадж его заслать. [Описание, как сделать похожее приложение](http://blog.apitron.com/2015/04/create-pdf-forms-in-ios-applications-using-xamarin-pdf-library-by-apitron.html).

Вот ещё свежая [статья, как создать универсальное приложение для Windows Store](http://blog.apitron.com/2015/03/create-and-load-PDF-forms-in-universal-applications-using-windows-store-and-windows-phone-PDF-library.html) (Windows Phone). Опросник который сохраняет результаты в PDF.